# Apply a function to return a row from a list containing many data.frames

Tags: r

I have a data.frame called `newdata` which looks like :

```
HospitalName         State     Rating
CRESTWOOD MEDICAL    AL        3
GEORGIANA HOSPITAL   AL        7
WEST VALLEY HOSPITAL AZ        5
VERDE VALLEY         AZ        6
```

The hospitals are sorted by State and then by Rating.  There are around 50 states present.

I'm splitting the data.frame into a list containing data.frames separated by State.

```
s <-split(newdata,newdata[,2],drop=FALSE)
```

I have a function that should take the nth row or top or bottom row from the individual data.frames in the list.  `num` contains either the row number or the text best or worst.

```
rnk<- function(num = "best") {

if(num=="best"){idx<-1}
if(num=="worst"){idx<-nrow(s)}  

best_hospital<-data.frame(s[idx,1],s[idx,2])
best_hospital

}
```

I'm calling `lapply()` to apply the function above to the list.

```
hospitals<- lapply(s, rnk,num=num )
```

I receive an error

> Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : unused argument (X[[1]])

All I'm trying to do is loop through the different data.frames and take the top, bottom or nth row and combine.  I think the bit I'm missing is how to refer to the individual data.frames from within the function.  Any ideas?

Comment: The first argument to your `rnk` function will be the data frame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is poorly defined and has nothing to do with the data you are operating on. In other words, what's `s` in your function? You didn't parse any `s` to it. Functions work in local environment, so don't expect it to understand what's `s` if you don't parse it. What is `num = num` in your `lapply` loop? You didn't define `num` anywhere

This is how your function should look like

```
rnk<- function(x, num = "best") {

  if(num=="best"){idx<-1}
  if(num=="worst"){idx<-nrow(x)}  

  data.frame(x[idx,1],x[idx,2])

}
```

And this is how you run it

```
lapply(s, rnk) # if you want default behaviour, i.e., num = "best"

lapply(s, rnk, "worst") # if you want to change num
```

And because @Spacedman decided to add a `dplyr` solution, here's a `data.table` solution too

```
library(data.table)
setDT(newdata) # Or newdata <- as.data.table(newdata) for older data.table versions
newdata[, .SD[which.max(Rating)], by = State]
#    State      HospitalName Rating
# 1:    AL GEORGIANAHOSPITAL      7
# 2:    AZ       VERDEVALLEY      6

newdata[, .SD[which.min(Rating)], by = State]
#    State       HospitalName Rating
# 1:    AL   CRESTWOODMEDICAL      3
# 2:    AZ WESTVALLEYHOSPITAL      5
```

Comment: I have it returning a list of hospitals but is there a way I can convert this into a clean data.frame?

Comment: See my edit. Use `data.table` (or `dplyr`) for both efficiency and easy syntax

Comment: Rather than using the Rating I need to refer to the specific row as indicated by num.  num can contain the row number or "Best" or "Worst"

Answer (score 1):

Define `rnk` thus:

```
rnk = function(d, num="best"){
  if(num=="best"){idx<-1}
  if(num=="worst"){idx<-nrow(d)}
  data.frame(d[idx,1],d[idx,2])
}
```

Then:

```
lapply(s, rnk, num="worst")
```

`lapply` calls your function for each element in `s` as its first argument, here `d`.

Of course this kind of thing might be easier with `dplyr`:

Get best within State groups:

```
> require(dplyr)
> newdata %.% group_by(State) %.% filter(Rating==max(Rating))
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: State

  HospitalName State Rating
1          Bar    AL      7
2          Qux    AZ      6
```

Or get worst:

```
> newdata %.% group_by(State) %.% filter(Rating==min(Rating))
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: State

  HospitalName State Rating
1          Foo    AL      3
2          Baz    AZ      5
```